# Remove some xtick labels from a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, x-axis, catplot

In the screenshot below, all my x-labels are overlapping each other.

```
g = sns.factorplot(x='Age', y='PassengerId', hue='Survived', col='Sex', kind='strip', data=train);
```

I know that I can remove all the labels by calling `g.set(xticks=[])`, but is there a way to just show some of the Age labels, like 0, 20, 40, 60, 80?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am not sure why there aren't sensible default ticks and values like there are on the y-axis.

The `FormatStrFormatter` instance is necessary to supply `set_major_formatter`. The `%d` is from the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
sns.factorplot(x='age',y='fare',hue='survived',col='sex',data=titanic,kind='strip')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=20))
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

This also works with `catplot`, which replaced `factorplot`

```py
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
sns.catplot(x='age', y='fare', hue='survived', col='sex', data=titanic, kind='strip')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=20))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: **I am not sure why there aren't sensible default ticks**: because `factorplot` (now `catplot`) is for a categorical independent variable.

Answer (score 0):

- `factorplot` is intended for use when the main independent variable is categorical, and has been renamed to [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

  - [v0.3.0 (March 2014) New plotting functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.3.0.html#new-plotting-functions) introduces `factorplot`.
  - [v0.9.0 (July 2018) API Changes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.9.0.html?highlight=factorplot#api-changes) renames to `catplot`.
- The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38809632/7758804), in general, offers a solution for spacing the xticks.
- The **primary issue** is this should be a quantitative plot, not a categorical plot, and is why there's an xtick for every category.

  - The **correct** type of plot is [`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) with [`kind='scatter'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

    - These were added [v0.9.0 (July 2018)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.9.0.html?highlight=relplot#new-relational-plots), so a more cumbersome implementation may have been required.
- The primary takeaway is to use the correct type of plot, **categorical**, or **quantitative**.

  - **categorical** plots will always show all of the xticks.
  - **quantitative** plots will usually format the step size of the xticks.

    - All xticks will be shown if the values used for the x-axis are `strings`, instead of `datetime` or `numeric`.

```py
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
g = sns.relplot(x='age', y='fare', hue='survived', col='sex', data=titanic)
```

[image]

- Without `relplot` and `scatterplot`, this could have been plotted directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) (or [`ax.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html)), but this is a more complex implementation.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 5), sharex=True)

axes = axes.flat

for ax, (sex, data) in zip(axes, titanic.groupby('sex')[['survived', 'age', 'fare']]):
    ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
    for (survived, sel), color in zip(data.groupby('survived'), ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange']):
        sel.plot(kind='scatter', x='age', y='fare', ec='w', s=30,
                 color=color, title=sex.title(), label=survived, ax=ax)
        
axes[0].get_legend().remove()
axes[1].legend(title='Survived', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]